# How do I set my FileFilter based on a Map in my custom ComboboxModel?

Tags: java, jcombobox, jfilechooser, filefilter, comboboxmodel

I'll briefly explain what I have going on and then provide some of my code.

I have a small GUI where I select an option on the JComboBox and then click a button that will open a JFileChooser which should filter out the files based on the selection in the JComboBox.

For instance, the user selects `Text File` from the JComboBox and when the user clicks the button it will open the JFileChooser showing only directories and text files.

In my main class I have this in the constructor:

```
public MyApp() {
    //init components and other logic

    comboBox.setModel(new FileExtensionModel());
}
```

Then in that class I have method for the button that opens the filechooser:

```
private void openFilAction(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(myFileType) || f.isDirectory();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "myFileType";
        }
    }

    int choose = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    //do logic  
}
```

And last is my basic extension of the DefaultComboBoxModel:

```
public class FileExtensionModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {
    Map<String, String> selection;

    public FileExtensionModel() {
        selection = new HashMap<String, String>();
        selection.put("Text File", ".txt");
        selection.put("Rar File", ".rar");
        selection.put("Zip File", ".rar");
        selection.put("Tar File", ".tar");
        selection.put("Ini File", ".ini");

        for(String key : select.keySet()) {
           this.addElement(key);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering how I can replace `myFileType` with the value from the map inside my `FileExtensionModel()` since I don't have access to it from my inner `FileFilter()` class.

Any suggestions are welcome, I don't mind moving code around a bit. It would be great if I could handle the majority of it in my FileExtensionModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you create your `HashMap` outside `FileExtensionModel`, where it is visible to the `FileFilter` and pass it to the constructor of `FileExtensionModel?

```
public class MyClass {

    Map<String, String> selection;
    FileExtensionModel fem;

    MyClass() {
        selection = new HashMap<String, String>();
        selection.put("Text File", ".txt");
        selection.put("Rar File", ".rar");
        selection.put("Zip File", ".rar");
        selection.put("Tar File", ".tar");
        selection.put("Ini File", ".ini");
        fem = new FileExtensionModel(selection);
    }
}

private void openFilAction(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(myFileType) || f.isDirectory();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            for (String key : selection.keySet()) {
               if (selection.get(key).equals(myFileType)) {
                   return key;
               }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    int choose = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    //do logic  
}
```

Your FileExtensionModel class:

```
public class FileExtensionModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {

    public FileExtensionModel(HashMap select) {

        for(String key : select.keySet()) {
           this.addElement(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can create a `HashMap` of FileFilters, with the extension being the key.

```
selection = new HashMap<String, String>();
            selection.put("Text File", ".txt");
            selection.put("Rar File", ".rar");
            selection.put("Zip File", ".rar");
            selection.put("Tar File", ".tar");
            selection.put("Ini File", ".ini");
            fem = new FileExtensionModel(selection);

HashMap<String, FileFilter> fileFilters = new HashMap<String, FileFilter>();

for (String key : selection.keySet()) {
    fileFilters.add(new MyFileFilter(key, selection.get(key)));
}
```

Then create a class for your FileFilter.

```
public class MyFileFilter extends FileFiter() {

    String extension;
    String description;

    public MyFileFilter(String extension, String description) {
        this.extension = extension;
        this.description = description;
   }

    ....
}
```

Comment: That is a possibility, but I still wouldn't be able to set the FileFilter since `myFileType` is declared outside of the `FileFilter()`. On that same note, I don't think that it would have access to `selection` either?

Comment: I thought `myFileType` was a field. Then you can create another HashMap<String, FileFilter>, where the key is the extension. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, I could change the value from String to FileFilter, but is there a benefit of doing it that way over making the FileExtensionModel final like Steiner mentioned?

Comment: Having one FileFilter per extension has the advantage of no need to update their accept and description. Then you can set more than one FileFilter on the file chooser, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to the `FileExtensionModel` instance in your `MyApp` class by simply adding it as a field. Since it is instantiated in the constructor, this shouldn't be a problem. However, since you're using this in an anonymous inner class, the field needs to be `final`.

```
public class MyApp {
    private final FileExtensionModel fileExtensionModel;
    // ... your other fields

    public MyApp() {
        // ... you other init
        fileExtensionModel = new FileExtensionModel();
        comboBox.setModel(fileExtensionModel);
    }
}
```

Now, in the `openFileAction` method, you should have access to the fileExtensionModel field, and for example extract the selected item (or any other method you should need). Something like:

```
myFileType = fileExtensionModel.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Interesting, are there any downsides from making it final? This seems like a lot less work than the other solution.

Comment: Not in this case, no. Making it final just means that you can not change the `fileExtensionModel` reference in the `MyApp` class. It needs to be initialized when the `MyApp` class is instantiated, and you cannot set it to a different value later.